# wifi interface for raspberry pi device not found

Tags: web-interface

i am using raspberry pi 3 model b, the wifi was working well before but now some how it is not it keep saying no interface device. i have try ifconfig but it shows the Ethernet only 
the image shows what i have try to do 
[image]

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d







pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.23.80  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
    inet6 fe80::db11:ad3f:ebd5:5633  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:1a:77:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 155  bytes 13938 (13.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 76  bytes 12607 (12.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 11  bytes 714 (714.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 11  bytes 714 (714.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: it's `/etc` not `/ect` - but that won't prove anything.

Comment: what is the output of `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: in the link is what I got https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QOS7WiqkWGo0BZOi9YOBFSklkzqSOAqI

Comment: It is always better to paste the text of the error rather than a screenshot, as a screenshot is not searchable. Please edit and update your question, with the text shown in the screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @Greenonline Ah, I always use screen shot using camera or scrot, for 2 reasons: (1) I always forget which terminal commands to cat or pipe etc, screen capture is much easier for me (2)  screen shot makes sure I have not made mistakes in copying and pasting.

Comment: @mo7d95.  On second thought, /boot/config.txt or other config files might have disabled wifi detect on boot.  So I disabled wifi on boot and get the error message as yours.  And iImmediately I inserted a wifi dongle, and it is detected without rebooting.  So you have a get around by using a wifi dongle, ... I am going to  update my answer soon.

Comment: I was addressing the OP. Besides. it's pretty difficult to copy and paste incorrectly.